# SDK not installing while setting up Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I have been trying to install Android Studio. Each step happens correctly and at the last downloading stage after all setting up it shows "Google APIs Intel x86_64 atom system image Android Emulator hypervisor driver (installer) and 5 more SDK components were not installed".[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEWzj.jpg)

[Image of Final downloading stage where error occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM2kn.jpg)

I tried re-installing it...checking if all the components like Android SDK, Android Platform & Android Virtual Device are checked. (Did this 3 times but still the problem persisted)

Comment: From the error, it seems like you are having an internet issue (connection reset). Are you downloading the appropriate Android Studio for your machine?

Comment: @tomerpacific I have Asus tuf gaming f15 and the version I am installing is Android studio lguana 2023.2.1

Comment: Do you have enough storage space on your hard drive? Also, have you tried using a VPN to download?

Comment: @tomerpacific yes my hard drive has ample space....I downloaded A.S in different O.S and it downloaded perfectly...Idk why it is giving issues in windows and yes haven't use VPN yet.